Why are the relationships in the table not working properly?
There is a database in the project and I want my user to be able to create code sections and they are saved in the database, also the user can like other people's code, and these liked CodeSnippets get to him in the LikedCodeSnippets property, and in his relation CodeSnippet in the UsersWhoLiked property, for some reason it works, when starting the project I get this error: "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_CodeSnippetUser_Users_UsersWhoLikedId' on table 'CodeSnippetUser' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."
The CodeSnippets property stores the code created by it if anything
Here is the code of the database context:
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CodeSnippet> CodeSnippets { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.CodeSnippets)
            .WithOne(c => c.User).HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.LikedCodeSnippets)
            .WithMany(c => c.UsersWhoLiked);
    }
}

And here are my 2 models,
User model:
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public required string Email { get; set; }
    public required string HashPassword { get; set; }
    public List<CodeSnippet> CodeSnippets { get; set; } = new List<CodeSnippet>();
    public List<CodeSnippet> LikedCodeSnippets { get; set; } = new List<CodeSnippet>();
    public IdentityData? IdentityData { get; set; }
}

CodeSnippet model:
public class CodeSnippet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; } = null!;
    public List<User> UsersWhoLiked { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public required string Title { get; set; }
    public required string Description { get; set; }
    public required string Content { get; set; }
    public required string Tag { get; set; }
}

I tried updating the database, adding and applying migrations but that's not the problem, it's the models that are the problem
Please try to give an answer so that I can just have a CodeSnippet object and a User to understand if this user has liked this CodeSnippet and get the people who have liked this CodeSnippet preferably as a collection. I will be glad to get any answers, thanks!

Also post the CREATE TABLE scripts of the tables involved.

How do you do that? Migrations are not created just because of an error, please explain it to me

In SSMS, you go to the database, right-click on the table, and select Script Table as --> Create to --> New Query Editor Window.

I found a solution, the problem is that if the user is deleted, what do CodeSnippet models do, namely their one-to-many relationship, I had to set the Nullable type for the foreign key and the User property
